# Why need default after require() method in Vue?

Tags: vue.js

There are 2 projects generated by vue-cli.

one of it I could add component like this code below:

```
Vue.component('HeaderBar',require("./components/common/HeaderBar.vue"));
```

But another one I can't do this , I must code like this:

```
Vue.component('HeaderBar',require("./components/common/HeaderBar.vue").default);
```

if not, I will get this error message:

```
Failed to mount component: template or render function not defined
```

Is anyone could tell me Why like this ？

Thank you for help .

Answer (score 8, accepted):

When using ES6 imports (export default HeaderBar), the exported module is of the format {"default" : HeaderBar}. The import statement handles this assignment for you, however, you have to do the require("./mycomponent").default conversion yourself. The HMR interface code cannot use import as it doesn't work inline.

If you want to avoid that, use module.exports instead of export default.

Comment: Thank you very much ! Another question is , why first project I can require component without default property ?

Comment: I want do that but I have no reputation enough :(