# Failed to mount component

Tags: vue.js, components, vue-component

What is the difference between:

```
Vue.component('cond',require('./components/myComponent.vue').default);
```

and

```
Vue.component('cond',require('./components/myComponent.vue'));
```

when I need to use the first or last one?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why need default after require() method in Vue?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215705/why-need-default-after-require-method-in-vue)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This really has nothing to do with Vue.js, but here's the difference:

```
require('./components/myComponent.vue')
```

returns whatever `./components/myComponent.vue` exports via `module.exports`.

So `require('./components/myComponent.vue').default` returns the `default` property of the `module.exports` mentioned above.

What you need to use depends on how your project is setup. To read more about it, search for info on Node.js modules.