# Correct way to handle click event in single file Vue component

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

What is the correct way to handle a click event inside a single file Vue component? Right now I have the code looking like below, but no luck.

```
<template>
    <button class="btn" @click="do_something">
        Delete
    </button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        methods: {
            do_something() {
                alert("Do something");
            }
        }   
    }
</script>
```

I have the above file in a vile called TestComponent.vue and included in app.js like

```
Vue.component('test', require('./components/TestComponent.vue').default);
```

I am using the component inside Laravel, so I need to compile it to make it all work. When I run `npm run dev` compiling starts but at a certain moment I receive an error.

Module build failed (from ./node_modules/vue-loader/lib/loaders/templateLoader.js):
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:725)

Comment: Hi Marc, so what seems to be the problem? This should work!

Comment: @RonaldEvers added more details and error message.

Comment: Is there a reason you need to use `Vue.component` and `require` rather than using `import` and the `components` key in `app.js` ?

Comment: It's how the example component is included in Laravel... just copied it... did not look into the difference between the two yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the `v-on:click` notation instead of the `@click` shorthand. So:

```
<button class="btn" v-on:click="do_something">
```

I'm not sure why the `@click` would not work in your case.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not solve the problem, when I remove the @click part, the component compiled without any problem.

Comment: `.default` is required in this use-case: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/46216854/9203110

Comment: How about trying with the short-hand syntax then, @MarcWitteveen: `<button v-on:click="do_something">` instead of `@click`?

Comment: That did the trick. However, it does not make any sense to me why that worked and not @click...

Comment: Cool! Updated the answer accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id="example">
  <button @click="greet">Greet</button>
</div>
<script>
var vm = new Vue({
  el: '#example',
  data: {
    name: 'Vue.js'
  },//say you have a variation of this
  methods: {
    greet(event) {
      alert('Hello ' + this.name + '!')
      alert(event.target.tagName)
    }
  }
})
</script>
```

this should work and it`s the same as your code so probably the error is an typo of yours.
show the whole page