# Reuse Vue component in html with unpkg

Tags: html, vue.js, vue-component, unpkg

Struggling a lot to reuse a Vue component (vue-json-pretty) through unpkg.
I guess I missing some basics but could not manage to sort it myself.

My HTML:

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/fiori-fundamentals@latest/dist/fiori-fundamentals.min.css"/>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue/dist/vue.js"></script>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/fundamental-vue@latest/dist/FundamentalVue.umd.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/vue-json-pretty@1.7.0/lib/styles.css"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue-json-pretty@1.7.0/lib/vue-json-pretty.js"></script>

<div id="app">
  <div>
    <vue-json-pretty
      :path="'res'"
      :data="{ key: 'value' }"
      @click="handleClick">
    </vue-json-pretty>
  </div>
  <div>
    <fd-popover v-fd-margin:large placement="bottom-start" with-arrow>
      <h1 v-fd-margin:large>
         Hello Fundamental Vue 
      </h1>
      <template #control="{toggle}">
        <fd-button @click="toggle">Show Popover</fd-button>
      </template>
    </fd-popover>
  </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```js
new Vue({ 
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    json: '{"count":3}'
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick: function() {
      console.log("clicked!")
    },
  },
})
```

Error Message:

> "[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element:  - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the 'name' option.
> (found in )"

[code in codepen](https://codepen.io/mitch0667/pen/KKMVQGW)

https://github.com/leezng/vue-json-pretty

Any help for my codepen example to work will be much appreciated :)

Comment: until unless you register vue-json-pretty using component property vue doesnt know what is that tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to declare vue-json-pretty as component. otherwise Vue dont know what is that tag. Declare it at top like this

```
Vue.component("vue-json-pretty", VueJsonPretty.default);
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    json: '{"count":4}'
  },
  methods: {
    handleClick: function() {
      console.log("clxicked!")
    },
  },
})
```

Comment: Hi Khaleel, just updated codepen with your suggestion and i ow get extra errors:
`"[Vue warn]: Invalid component name: '0'. Component names should conform to valid > custom element name in html5 specification."`
`"[Vue warn]: Invalid value for option 'components': expected an Object, but got Array. found in <Anonymous>)"`
`"[Vue warn]: Unknown custom element: <vue-json-pretty> - did you register the component correctly? For recursive components, make sure to provide the 'name' option.(found in <Root>)"`

Comment: @Mitch0667 check my fork https://codepen.io/khaleel06/pen/XWKXBBG
hope it helps

Comment: Thanks a lot @Khaleel, that works perfectly :)
I will accept your answer once it is updated as per your codepen!
Do you know the reason of `.default` in `Vue.component("vue-json-pretty", VueJsonPretty.default);`?

Comment: Glad it helped. please accept the answer and upvote if it helped.

Comment: Refer this for why default is required https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46215705/why-need-default-after-require-method-in-vue

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks again for help! Answer accepted